# Can directory names and file names be variables in cgi perl scripting

Tags: perl, file, cgi

I know that file names can be variable in perl scripting.Does the same apply to cgi-perl scripting.Because when I used variables inside open statement I get the error No such file or directory.But when I directly mention the path the file is opened for reading.These variables are passed from a form. The values are passed correctly they are not empty(Checked by printing the varaiables).

**Example:**

```
$dir=abc;
$file=file1;

open (FILE, '/var/www/cgi-bin/$dir/$file')
    or print "file cannot be opened $!\n";
```

**Error:**

`file cannot be opened no such file or directory`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes to interpolate variables:

```
open (FILE, "/var/www/cgi-bin/$dir/$file")
#    here __^                and here __^
    or print "file cannot be opened $!\n";
```

Also, ALWAYS

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

By using single quotes, the varibles aren'tt interpolated, so you're trying to open literally `/var/www/cgi-bin/$dir/$file` and it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Raju: because variables inside single quotes are not interpolation. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators

Answer (score 1):

You've got (and accepted) a good answer. I just wanted to add that you can make your error message a lot more helpful if you include the value of `$file` in the string.

```
my $file_path = '/var/www/cgi-bin/$dir/$file';
open (FILE, $file_path)
    or print "file [$file_path] cannot be opened: $!\n";
```

Then the error would have been "file [/var/www/cgi-bin/$dir/$file] cannot be opened: no such file or directory" which would have made it obvious that the variables weren't being expanded.

**Update:** I was talking nonsense. The new version is better.

Comment: Are you sure you will get that error as you mentioned? In the below part [$file] will be expanded as its in double quote. isnt it?